# PHP bitwise operations not returning correct values

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, bitmask, comparison-operators

I have a function which takes a numbers and returns an array corresponding to the days (the number will be bit-masked for each day of the week). However the array is returning all the days for certain values and an empty array for another values.
Below is the function

```
function get_days($days) {
    $days_arr = array();


echo "days: " . decbin($days) . " - type: " . gettype($days) . "<br/>";
echo "type1: " . gettype($days & 0x01) . " - type2: " . gettype(0x01) . "<br/>";
echo "days & 0x01 = " . dechex($days & 0x01) . " = " . ($days & 0x01 == 0x01) . "<br/>";
echo "days & 0x02 = " . dechex($days & 0x02) . " = " . ($days & 0x02 == 0x02) . "<br/>";
echo "days & 0x04 = " . dechex($days & 0x04) . " = " . ($days & 0x04 == 0x04) . "<br/>";
echo "days & 0x08 = " . dechex($days & 0x08) . " = " . ($days & 0x08 == 0x08) . "<br/>";
echo "days & 0x10 = " . dechex($days & 0x10) . " = " . ($days & 0x10 == 0x10) . "<br/>";


    if($days & 0x01 == 0x01)
        $days_arr[] = 'M';

    if($days & 0x02 == 0x02)
        $days_arr[] = 'T';

    if($days & 0x04 == 0x04)
        $days_arr[] = 'W';

    if($days & 0x08 == 0x08)
        $days_arr[] = 'H';

    if($days & 0x10 == 0x10)
        $days_arr[] = 'F';

    return $days_arr;
}
```

Below are the results of the echo

```
days: 10101 - type: integer
type1: integer - type2: integer
days & 0x01 = 1 = 1
days & 0x02 = 0 = 1
days & 0x04 = 4 = 1
days & 0x08 = 0 = 1
days & 0x10 = 10 = 1
days: 1010 - type: integer
type1: integer - type2: integer
days & 0x01 = 0 = 0
days & 0x02 = 2 = 0
days & 0x04 = 0 = 0
days & 0x08 = 8 = 0
days & 0x10 = 0 = 0
```

I can't seem to figure the reason behind the issue, it seems logical to me that this should work.

Comment: This is an operator precedence issue. The bitwise expression should be parenthesized because the comparison has higher precedence so it happens before the bitwise operation. In your if statements, the syntax that gives you the desired result would be `if( ($days & 0x08) == 0x08)`.  See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php And http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an operator precedence issue. See:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

So `==` is above `&`. You should not do:

```
$days & 0x02 == 0x02
```

But:

```
($days & 0x02) == 0x02
```